# How do I configure the timezone of Fluentd?

Tags: timezone, fluentd

**my system time is :Tue Jan  6 09:44:49 CST 2015**

td-agent.conf :

```
<match apache.access>
  type webhdfs
  host Page on test.com
  port 50070
  path /apache/%Y%m%d_%H/access.log.${hostname}
  time_slice_format %Y%m%d
  time_slice_wait 10m

  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%:z
  timezone +08:00
  flush_interval 1s
</match>
```

**the time of dir is right!**

```
[hadoop@node1 ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /apache/20150106_09
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   2 webuser supergroup      17496 2015-01-06 09:47 /apache/20150106_09/access.log.node1.Page on test.com
```

**but the time of log is wrong,I don't know why?**

```
2015-01-06T01:47:00.000+00:00   apache.access   {"host":"::1","user":null,"method":"GET","path":"/06","code":404,"size":275,"referer":null,"agent":"ApacheBench/2.3"}
20
```

Answer (score 0):

my config is ok.

```
    type webhdfs
    host 192.168.80.41
    port 50070
    path /log/fluent_%Y%m%d_%H.log
    time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
    localtime
    flush_interval 10s
```

add `localtime` on config.